# Construction: may vs shall

Tags: florida, hoa

Context:a Florida HOA bylaws indicate:

The passage below indicates `may`:

> Special meetings of the Board `may` be called by the president on
> five(5)days notice to each Director either personally or by mail ,
> facsimile transmission or electronic mail. Special meetings shall be
> called by the president or secretary in a like manner and on like
> notice on the written request of three (3) Directors.

A subsequent passage below indicates `shall`:

> Meetings ofthe Board of Administration `shall` be open to all unit
> owners. Notice of all meetings shall be posted on the official bulletin
> board ofthe Association at least forty-eight (48) hours in advance of
> each scheduled meeting and directed to the attention of all unit
> owners. In case of an emergency, a meeting of the Board of
> Administration may be held without notice.

Assume that a meeting minutes are provided as evidence.  It would seem that the language using `may` is a permissive and not a requirement.

Assume a 'corner case':  a meeting is scheduled on the 1st for the 4th of a given month.  **Is there any case law or any other reasoning process that wherein `may` nullifies such a meeting and effectively sets a requirement?**  Assume that meeting is posted with 48 hours notice so that only the shall / may language is the focus of any answer to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow the last bit of your question. Basically it is saying that the President can decide for themselves ("may") whether to call a **special** meeting - if they do then they have to give 5 days notice. All meetings (however they come about and whether they are special meetings or not) must be ("shall") open to al unit owners.

Comment: @Nemo  Thank you for responding: I think you are indicating that `may` sets forth a requirement.  Is there an a concrete example?  If yes, please consider creating an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: "May" sets out an option. The President may choose to call a special meeting. If he does then he has to give  5 days notice.  Alternatively three directors may request a special meeting and in that case the President/secretary has ("shall") to call one.

Comment: Basically "May" indicates something you can do if you want to but don't have to. "Shall" indicates something you have to do (are obliged to do).

Comment: @Nemo Don't answer in comments.

Comment: @Trish It wasn’t intended to be an answer. Just a step in understanding the question. I don’t understand the actual question I.e. the bit in bold type about nullification.

Comment: I suspect that the OP is not a native English speaker so clarifying the meaning of the words Shall and May was a step in helping the OP better formulate the question in bold.

Comment: @Nemo Gatorback is a native Englsh speaker.

Comment: FWIW I don't really understand what is being asked either.

Comment: @ohwilleke Most of it is very clear English but the words in bold - which is the actual question - makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 5):

## Shall

Whenever a law or legal text uses *shall* there is no discretion allowed. Read it as *has to* when it prescribes something. If it is written in the negative (shall not), you can read it as *it is forbidden* or *X is barred*.

- *[the] Congress of the United States [...] **shall** consist of a Senate and House of Representative*

  - This prescribes that the congress **has to** have these two parts, not more, not less.
- *Special meetings **shall** be called by the president or secretary in a like manner and on like notice on the written request of three (3) Directors.*

  - Whenever 3 directors sign letters demanding a meeting, then the president or secretary **has to** follow the process explained before.
- *Congress **shall make no law** [that does X]*

  - Note that this is a negative shall! Read it as *Congress is barred from doing a law that does X*.

Shall obviously can have exceptions or modifiers. Such often are in modifying sentences following them.

- *Meetings of the Board of Administration shall be open to all unit owners. Notice of all meetings shall be posted on the official bulletin board ofthe Association at least forty-eight (48) hours in advance of each scheduled meeting and directed to the attention of all unit owners. In case of an emergency, a meeting of the Board of Administration may be held without notice.*

  - There **has to** be a notice on the board at least 48 hours before a meeting, unless there is an emergency.

## May

Legal texts usually use *may* whenever there is an option to do something. It usually marks the possibility to do something and vesting the discretion to do so in somebody. Often, they come with a minimum or maximum time an event has to occur from a deadline.

- *The department **may** enter an order doing one or more of the following if the department finds that a person has violated or is operating in violation of any of the provisions of this section or the orders issued under this section:*

  - The decision **if** something happens is vested in the department [of Agriculture and Consumer Services]. If they decide to act, then it has to come from the list that follows the section.
- *Special meetings of the Board **may** be called by the president on five(5)days notice to each Director [...]*

  - It is at the discretion of the president to call a special meeting. If they do, it has to be done with 5 (or more) days warning to the Directors. Including the *other* paragraph of OPs document, then it *also* has to be posted 48 hours before the meeting on the board, unless it is emergency.